# Icefaces and Tomcat Crash

Tags: java, tomcat, icefaces-1.8

I have an application made with ICEfaces and ran on Tomcat 6. When I try to access one of the pages where I select users, if gives me this error. The weird thing is, after I get the error, I refresh the page, and it normally goes to where ever I needed it to go to.

Does anyone know what the error actually means, because the lines of code that are highlighted are closing of a DB connection, a comment line (weird lol), and some other syntax stuff that can't have errors in it.

```
exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapped Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:156)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)

    root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    crm.CRM_SA_enter.reload_Fees(CRM_SA_enter.java:3591)
    crm.CRM_SA_enter.gradeEval(CRM_SA_enter.java:3844)
    crm.CRM_SA_enter.apply_dropDown(CRM_SA_enter.java:3265)
    crm.CRM_SA_enter.load_function2(CRM_SA_enter.java:2314)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:380)
    com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries$RowEvent.broadcast(UISeries.java:617)
    com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.broadcast(UISeries.java:285)
    com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries$RowEvent.broadcast(UISeries.java:617)
    com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.broadcast(UISeries.java:285)
    com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.PanelTabSet.broadcast(PanelTabSet.java:320)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:475)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:756)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:18)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.renderCycle(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:132)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.ReceiveSendUpdates.service(ReceiveSendUpdates.java:74)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.RequestVerifier.service(RequestVerifier.java:31)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionVerifier.service(SessionVerifier.java:26)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
crm.CRM_SA_enter.reload_Fees(CRM_SA_enter.java:3591)
```

Has the NPE. Doesn't look like IceFaces code at all, probably what you are building.